# Spree - Avoiding Large Number of Product Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am building a **Spree** based store front for a cake and sweets producer. I have come across a point which I am finding it difficult to resolve with my knowledge.

Cakes have many options

- Size (price decider)
- Filling
- Sponge
- Icing and so on...

If taking them as `Spree::OptionType` and `Spree::OptionValue` these make a sizzling 72,000 variants for a single cake. But only the Size decides the price.

### Not So Nice Plan

The number of variants are beyond humane limits. Thus without needing to make all the variants in the back end I was thinking of making them on the fly by overriding the **Add to cart** feature in more or less 'Create on Miss' fashion.

This approach has 2 issues

- Massive number of combinations - 72,000 and will definitely grow
- Cant find a credible way of setting the price

### Alternative Approach

- Create custom models

  - `Spree::AlternativeOptionType`
  - `Spree::AlternativeOptionValue`
  - And other supportive tables to link data
- Add admin controls to make the relations

That is quite some work I believe, I would like to know any suggestions of yours to solve my issues.

### My interest

Is there some thing like Spree Options that don't necessarily make variants, but is global. For example, doesn't need to be defined for every product?

If not an alternative way to `Spree::Options` for other product types.

Answer (score 2):

Because of weird SO requirements I can't comment on your question - the only option to communicate is giving an answer... OK, so, have you considered the product assembly approach? https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-product-assembly

For me it seems like a cake is actually being build with small other products (icing, filling...). I've never tried that gem so can't really say if it's worth a try.